# find a specific word in external page

Tags: php, dom

How to find a specific word in a external page using php ?
(dom or pregmatch, or what else ?)

example in foo.com source code with :

> span name="abcd"

I want to check if the word abcd is in foo.com in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$v = file_get_contents("http://foo.com");
echo substr_count($v, 'abcd'); // number of occurences

//or single match

echo substr_count($v, ' abcd ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('/span\s+name\=\"abcd\"/i', $str)) echo 'exists!';
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a string of characters exist:

```
<?php

$term = 'abcd';

if ( preg_match("/$term/", $str) ) { 

    // yes it does

}

?>
```

To check if that string exists as a word in its own right (ie, is not in the middle of a larger word) use word boundary matchers:

```
<?php

$term = 'abcd';

if ( preg_match("/\b$term\b/", $str) ) { 

    // yes it does

}

?>
```

For a case-insensitive search, add the `i` flag after the last slash in the regex:

```
<?php

$term = 'abcd';

if ( preg_match("/\b$term\b/i", $str) ) { 

    // yes it does

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are other few ways to find specific word

```
<?php
$str = 'span name="abcd"';

if (strstr($str, "abcd")) echo "Found: strstr\n";
if (strpos($str, "abcd")) echo "Found: strpos\n";
if (ereg("abcd", $str)) echo "Found: ereg\n";
if (substr_count($str, 'abcd')) echo "Found: substr_count\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = 'foo.php';
file_get_contents($name);
$contents=$pattern = preg_quote('abcd', '/');
// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
  echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
echo "not exist word";
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be the right answer, but please explain what this code is doing and why this answer adds value. Read this topic to create good quality answers.[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)